# Why is this function not removing the outliers?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, outliers, indices

I am working with a data set that I am loading from a csv file.

```py
H2O_data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/water_potability_raw.csv")
H2O_data.head(10)
```

```
    ph  Hardness    Solids  Chloramines Sulfate Conductivity    Organic_carbon  Trihalomethanes Turbidity   Potability
0   NaN 204.890456  20791.31898 7.300212    368.516441  564.308654  10.379783   86.990970   2.963135    0
1   3.716080    129.422921  18630.05786 6.635246    NaN 592.885359  15.180013   56.329076   4.500656    0
2   8.099124    224.236259  19909.54173 9.275884    NaN 418.606213  16.868637   66.420093   3.055934    0
3   8.316766    214.373394  22018.41744 8.059332    356.886136  363.266516  18.436525   100.341674  4.628771    0
4   9.092223    181.101509  17978.98634 6.546600    310.135738  398.410813  11.558279   31.997993   4.075075    0
5   5.584087    188.313324  28748.68774 7.544869    326.678363  280.467916  8.399735    54.917862   2.559708    0
6   10.223862   248.071735  28749.71654 7.513408    393.663395  283.651634  13.789695   84.603556   2.672989    0
7   8.635849    203.361523  13672.09176 4.563009    303.309771  474.607645  12.363817   62.798309   4.401425    0
8   NaN 118.988579  14285.58385 7.804174    268.646941  389.375566  12.706049   53.928846   3.595017    0
9   11.180284   227.231469  25484.50849 9.077200    404.041635  563.885481  17.927806   71.976601   4.370562    0
```

All values are numerical but there are some empty cells (NaN).

I copy the data frame to another one, so that the H2O_data stays unmodified for the rest of the program.

```py
non_null_rows = H2O_data.copy(deep=True)
```

I then impute the missing values:

```py
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
non_null_rows = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(non_null_rows), columns = non_null_rows.columns)
```

```py
non_null_rows.head(10)
```

```
    ph  Hardness    Solids  Chloramines Sulfate Conductivity    Organic_carbon  Trihalomethanes Turbidity   Potability
0   6.007427    204.890456  20791.31898 7.300212    368.516441  564.308654  10.379783   86.990970   2.963135    0.0
1   3.716080    129.422921  18630.05786 6.635246    326.479827  592.885359  15.180013   56.329076   4.500656    0.0
2   8.099124    224.236259  19909.54173 9.275884    357.947334  418.606213  16.868637   66.420093   3.055934    0.0
3   8.316766    214.373394  22018.41744 8.059332    356.886136  363.266516  18.436525   100.341674  4.628771    0.0
4   9.092223    181.101509  17978.98634 6.546600    310.135738  398.410813  11.558279   31.997993   4.075075    0.0
5   5.584087    188.313324  28748.68774 7.544869    326.678363  280.467916  8.399735    54.917862   2.559708    0.0
6   10.223862   248.071735  28749.71654 7.513408    393.663395  283.651634  13.789695   84.603556   2.672989    0.0
7   8.635849    203.361523  13672.09176 4.563009    303.309771  474.607645  12.363817   62.798309   4.401425    0.0
8   7.805297    118.988579  14285.58385 7.804174    268.646941  389.375566  12.706049   53.928846   3.595017    0.0
10  7.360640    165.520797  32452.61441 7.550701    326.624353  425.383420  15.586810   78.740016   3.662292    0.0
```

I wrote the below function to remove the outliers for each column. I want to remove them from first column, then use the new data set to remove them from the second, and so on.

```py
def remove_outliers(dataset, col_name):
    Q1  = dataset[col_name].quantile(0.25) 
    Q3  = dataset[col_name].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1

    upper = np.where(dataset[col_name] >= (Q3 + 1.5*IQR)) # Upper bound, indices
    lower = np.where(dataset[col_name] <= (Q1 - 1.5*IQR)) # Lower bound, indices

    ''' Removing the Outliers '''
    dataset.drop(upper[0], inplace=True, axis=0)
    dataset.drop(lower[0], inplace=True, axis=0)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10,0.5))  
    lab1 = [col_name, ' raw data']
    sns.boxplot(H2O_data[col_name], orient="h").set(xlabel=lab1)
    plt.show()

    plt.figure(figsize=(10,0.5))  
    lab2 = [col_name, ' no outliers']
    sns.boxplot(dataset[col_name], orient="h").set(xlabel=lab2)
    plt.show()

    dataset = dataset.reset_index(drop=True)
    return dataset
```

I try to remove them for the first column and I do not get any errors but not all of them are removed. Why is this happening?

```py
remove_outliers(non_null_rows, 'ph')
```

[boxplot ph for raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Xn8.png)
[boxplot ph without outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Usi.png)

And if I try to call the same function for the rest of the columns I only get errors.

```py
remove_outliers(non_null_rows, 'Hardness')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-d57d897abd60> in <module>
----> 1 remove_outliers(non_null_rows, 'Hardness')

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   6015         if mask.any():
   6016             if errors != "ignore":
-> 6017                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   6018             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   6019         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: '[2189] not found in axis'
```

I assume they are related to the indices of the rows after some rows have been removed but I tried to reset them inside the function and that doesn't help.

```py
dataset = dataset.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I am not sure the new function call works with the result of the previous function call, i.e. with the data frame that now has some rows removed.

I am lost. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: That `dataset = dataset.reset_index(drop=True)` is missing an `in_place=True`, which you're using elsewhere. It looks like it just creates a copy of the dataframe with the index reset. Are you using that copy, or continuing to use the original?

Comment: what version of `pandas` are you using? Your code isn't raising a `KeyError` for me (`pandas` 1.5.1, `numpy` 1.23.3)